# Can vsts agent connect to ADO using managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-managed-identity

I think it would make sense, to enable the VSTS build-agents being able to use managed identities of the build agents' VMs to authenticate with the ADO queue and poll the jobs.

Using PAT (personal access token) for that is a bit cumbersome.

Is there a support (or is it planned) for the VSTS agent and ADO to utilize the managed identities used in Azure for such purpose?

Thanks for answers / observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can vsts agent connect to ADO using managed identity?

For this issue , I am afraid this is currently not supported for agent.

Your agent can authenticate to Azure Pipelines using the following method:

**PAT is the only scheme that works with Azure Pipelines.**

[image]

This is clearly stated in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#authentication).

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. You could vote that suggestion ticket and share your comment there.The product team would provide the updates if they view it.